# Robotframework - get failing keyword / stack trace of failure

Tags: error-handling, robotframework, stack-trace

I have a keyword called "debug teardown" which prints the test status and then runs the debuglibrary Debug keyword, if the test has failed.

I would like to be able to log to console *which* keyword has caused the failure, so I can more effectively debug my test.

Is it possible to get the stack trace or most recent test keyword, and log it to the console?

Here is my `Debug Teardown` keyword:

```
Debug Teardown
    Run Keyword If Test Failed                  Log    ${TEST STATUS}: ${TEST MESSAGE}    ERROR
    Run Keyword If Test Failed                  Debug
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a bit more information if you create a [listener](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface) and also set the log level to `DEBUG`. Inside the listener you can save the results of log commands, and then when a keyword fails you can print it out or do whatever else you want.

For example, here's a listener that will print to stdout the last log message when a keyword fails:

```
from __future__ import print_function
class my_listener():
    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 2

    def __init__(self):
        self.ROBOT_LIBRARY_LISTENER = self
        self.last_log = None

    def _log_message(self, message):
        self.last_log = message

    def _end_keyword(self, name, attrs):
        if attrs['status'] == 'FAIL':
            print("\n******\n", self.last_log['message'])
```

You would use it by importing the listener like a normal library, and also setting the log level to DEBUG (otherwise you'll get the error but no stack trace).

Example:

```
*** Settings ***
Library      my_listener
Suite Setup  set log level  DEBUG

*** Test cases ***
Example
    some keyword
```

Comment: Totally unrelated, but an eye-opener for me - you can import listener modules as regular libraries in the suites. Come to think of it, it does sound natural, but I always thought _(obviously - wrongly)_ listeners are constrained to the execution; this opens a whole new world of possibilities :) Thank you for that!

Comment: @Todor: it's covered in the user guide in the section titled [Test libraries as listeners](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-libraries-as-listeners)

Comment: It definitely is, that's the first thing I've checked before dropping the "thank you" note, but that section writing style is such, that I have always missed it... :)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to utilize [set suite variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Suite%20Variable) to update a "global" variable as you go. The last set variable value would be the value that failed.

Comment: This is a solution but a pretty irritating one, as I'd have to change the suite variable every other line. ):

Comment: This is also not very clean solution - use of global variables should be kept to minimum by today's coding standards